# How to pass value through argument to another controller

Tags: php, laravel-4

I called a function from another controller then tried to pass the date value to the function but the date is `null`.

```
class TestController
{
  public function test () 
  {
    $pnl = App::make('RegisterController')->getData($init = ['startdate' => '2018-04-10','enddate' => '2019-04-10']);   
  } 
}

Class RegisterController
{
    public function getData($init = false)
    {
        $init = [
            'startdate' => Input::get('startdate', Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth()->toDateString()),
            'enddate' => Input::get('enddate', Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()->toDateString())
        ];
        Debugbar::info($init); // <----date is null

        return $init;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a piece of code which is going to be used again, try setting up facade pattern or you create helper function.

Comment: please specify what function have you called from which controller. Please also describe the expected behaviour and what you have tried to fix the actual one